# Graphing Comparisons of Sorting Algorithms

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, graphing

Task: **I need to graph the number of comparisons(y axis) to the number of arguments in my array(x axis) for Insertion Sort and Quick Sort.**

Question: I was wondering if I could use the average time complexities in order to do this.

Insertion Sort: O(n^2)= 1 element in my array(x axis) 1 comparison (y axis)

Quick Sort: O(n log(n)) = 1 element in my array(x axis) 0 comparisons ( y axis)

Similar/Helpful Question asked: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3/why-is-quicksort-better-than-other-sorting-algorithms-in-practice

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes,  unless you are required to use a counter in the sorting functions to obtain the actual number of comparisons done for each array length which will depened on the elements themselves.

Comment: No, I just need the average case, so this should be fine?

Comment: Is this an assignment?  If so, I can't realy answer that for sure not knowing the expectations of your prof, but probably.

Comment: Yes, it is an assignment, I don't think we need to be exact either